# Count SHA1 of NSData

Tags: objective-c, sha1

I need to count SHA1 checksum of NSData object. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a SHA1 function in the openssl lib (link with -lcrypto linker option):

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>

NSMutableData *hashData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA1([input bytes], [input length], [hashData mutableBytes]);
```

Comment: Does it return an NSString? because if I use it like [CODE] NSMutableData *hashData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
 NSString*temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:SHA1([myData bytes], [myData length], [hashData mutableBytes])]; [/CODE] I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Nope. You can do a [hashData description] after calling SHA1 to return an NSString.